# Confused about python shapely exception ctypes.ArgumentError

Tags: python-2.7, shapely

I just installed shapely and basic things seem fine. I started following an example in [this](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html) tutorial to get a feel for the library.

Specifically:

```
>>> from shapely.wkt import loads
>>> g = loads('POINT (0.0 0.0)')
>>> g.buffer(1.0).area        # 16-gon approx of a unit radius circle
3.1365484905459389
>>> g.buffer(1.0, 128).area   # 128-gon approximation
3.1415138011443009
>>> g.buffer(1.0, 3).area     # triangle approximation
3.0
>>> list(g.buffer(1.0, cap_style='square').exterior.coords)
[(1.0, 1.0), (1.0, -1.0), (-1.0, -1.0), (-1.0, 1.0), (1.0, 1.0)]
>>> g.buffer(1.0, cap_style='square').area
4.0
```

When I make the call to `g.buffer(1.0, cap_style='square')`, I get the following error:

```
  buf = list(shp.buffer(1.0, cap_style='square'))
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/shapely/geometry/base.py", line 538, in buffer
mitre_limit))
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/shapely/topology.py", line 78, in __call__
  return self.fn(this._geom, *args)
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 5: <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: wrong type
```

Reading the documentation [here](http://pydoc.net/Python/Shapely/1.5.1/shapely.geometry.base/) I saw that this example is in the comments in the shapely/geometry/base.py module. However I noticed that the default value for the cap_style argument is of type int (`CAP_STYLE.round`) and not string. Not sure if that means anything.

Does anyone have any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you answered your question yourself :) 
It is indeed the problem you mention. `cap_style` key argument must be an integer. And according to [shapely documentation](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html#object.buffer), only the following values are available.

> The styles of caps are specified by integer values: 1 (round), 2
>   (flat), 3 (square). These values are also enumerated by the object
>   shapely.geometry.CAP_STYLE.